# Using PHP with Google App Engine to administer Google Apps

Tags: php, api, google-app-engine, google-api-php-client

I am trying to create a Google App Engine Web application in **PHP** that is capable of administering my Google Apps users and groups and create detailed per-user reports.

The built-in PHP API is appallingly inadequate with seemingly no functionality to perform user administration so I wanted to use the [Google APIs Client Library for PHP](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) but I'm having trouble including this API in my Google Apps project.

Can anyone suggest how I can best approach this?

- Should I use the built-in PHP API provided by Google App Engine? If so, which classes can I use to perform user management?
- How can I use the [Google API PHP Cient](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) together with my Google App Engine?
- Should I just abandon Google App Engine and host the web app on my own servers?
- Should I use something else like Java instead of PHP?

Thanks in advance for any help and or suggestions on how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

Did you do a quick google search on using the Google API PHP Client from App Engine?

Is so, you might have seen [this](https://gae-php-tips.appspot.com/2013/08/06/using-the-google-apis-client-library-for-php-with-app-engine/) article which I guess explains the entire thing for you.

Answer (score 0):

In your project you need to select ADMIN SDK which should give you access to all api's realted to that. Directory API etc. 
At least that is what I think and how I have it setup. Only since I am a very little skills I struggle to use the PHP library ;)